# how to convert sqlite database to csv file format?

Tags: .net, sql

i have a sqlite database in sencha touch phonegap...when click export button, i want to convert the sqlite database to csv file...

following is my sqlite database...
table name is categorydet...

```
function database() 
{

var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(query, error);

}

function query(tx)
{
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categorydet(ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Date,Date2,Expenses,Exp,Amount,Payment,TotExp)');

}

function error(err)
{
Ext.Msg.alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
}
```

any idea...plz help me...if u have code...plz send...

Comment: plz dnt uz txtspk wn askng qns.

Answer (score 0):

1. It sounds like you're programming Javascript (phonegap has a Javascript API) on an Android phone (Android uses SqlLite).
2. It also sounds like you can successfully query the database.
3. Phonegap also has read and write file I/O APIs.
4. Simply:

   a) Make a SQL query ("select")

   b) Open a text file (e.g. create a FileWriter object)

   c) Fetch a row at a time, and write it in CSV format